# Azure Function logs once before startup and twice - after

Tags: c#, azure-functions, .net-6.0, serilog

I am migrating my .NET 7 function from isolated to .NET 6 in-process and having some issues with bringing Serilog back to life. With the help of other questions I changed from
`services.AddLogging(lb => { lb.AddSerilog(logger, true); });` to

```
Log.Logger = CreateLogger(configuration);

services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>(new Serilog.Extensions.Logging.SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger));
```

But this configuration produces logs only from Function host and not my Serilog logger.

```
[2023-09-28T12:26:39.875Z] Executing 'SendNewsletterCampaignFunction' (Reason='(null)', Id=6a73b015-3581-4fee-af14-3c6fab11b52e)
[2023-09-28T12:26:39.877Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 057c4e4fdc5043a6b75ecbea18de849d, SequenceNumber: 18, DeliveryCount: 4, EnqueuedTimeUtc: 2023-09-28T11:44:40.376000
0+00:00, LockedUntilUtc: 2023-09-28T12:31:40.3990000+00:00, SessionId: (null)
[2023-09-28T12:26:39.891Z] Received queue item {"CustomerId":"c3316eb5-2d04-4b0f-b3e4-25b263600018","LanguageId":"10b950a3-99bd-4c86-8e4c-7e339cf192dc","EmailQueueId":"19
fc2f16-fc3a-42d0-bdb0-beae9616bf7b"}
```

Here is my `CreateLogger` implementation. I tried adding `.WriteTo.Console`, but it does not replace Function host logs, so I start seeing the same log entry twice, once in Function host format, once - in serilog output template format.

```
public static Logger CreateLogger(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
            .WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage(
                outputTemplate:
                "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz}] [{Level}] [Customer:{CustomerId}] [Function:{Function}] [QueueItem:{QueueItem}] - {Message} {NewLine} {Exception}",
                connectionString: configuration.GetConnectionString("BlobStorageConnection"),
                storageContainerName: "email-function-logs",
                writeInBatches: true,
                period: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                retainedBlobCountLimit: 10000,
                blobSizeLimitBytes: 20 * 1024 * 1024,
                storageFileName: "log{yyyy}{MM}{dd}.txt")
        // .WriteTo.Console(
        //     outputTemplate:
        //     "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz}] [{Level}] [Customer:{CustomerId}] [Function:{Function}] [QueueItem:{QueueItem}] - {Message} {NewLine} {Exception}"
        // )
        ;

    var webhookUrl = configuration.GetConnectionString("TeamsNotificationWebhook");
    if (webhookUrl != null)
    {
        log = log.WriteTo.MicrosoftTeams(webhookUrl, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error);
    }

    return log.CreateLogger();
}
```

Without `.WriteTo.Console`:

[image]

And with: before startup logs are produced ONLY once and ONLY by Serilog, and twice - when function executes

[image]
[image]

Modifications to host.json did not help. I also tried setting it to `None`, but it did not help

```
"logging": {
  "applicationInsights": {
    "samplingSettings": {
      "isEnabled": true,
      "excludedTypes": "Request"
    }
  },
  "logLevel": {
    "MyApp.Emails.Functions": "Information"
  }
},
```

I create loggers using constructor injection of `ILogger<>`

I checked few questions that mention duplicate logs, but many of them end up on registering `ILoggerProvider` and that's it. Other questions are related to AppInsights and function being executed twice.

How do I fix the logger to log to Console only once and only with Serilog?